# Faster way to get stereo images at 640x480 from Raspberry pi

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi, image, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I have connected 2 logitech C930e web cameras to a Raspberry Pi3 running a Ubuntu Mate and ROS Kinetic. I want to process the images on my laptop and only remotely see what the Pi sees using ROS.

Using uvc_camera package and some tweaks, I am able to publish 320x240 grayscale stereo frames at about 5fps.

Output of rostopic delay is as follows,

```
average: 221.12KB/s
    mean: 76.85KB min: 76.85KB max: 76.85KB window: 36
average: 221.80KB/s
    mean: 76.85KB min: 76.85KB max: 76.85KB window: 39
```

From iftop i can see that for 2s the used bandwidth is 3.65Mb.

Could anyone help me as to how i can increase the speed of the transfer. ? I want to be able to work at atleast 15fps.

Also is it possible to run a live video stream using gstreamer or flask and then publish it to ros from the host system. ?

Thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255086/faster-way-to-get-stereo-images-at-640x480-from-raspberry-pi/) by [surajmshanbhag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29417/surajmshanbhag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2017-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using UDP for streaming.
https://github.com/surajshanbhag/Indoor_SLAM

---

Originally posted by [surajmshanbhag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29417/surajmshanbhag/) with karma: 61 on 2017-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2017-09-17**:
Try this if you already haven't https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=50075 @surajmshanbhag